# WIN32 API C Loading Image Logo in Dialog Application

Tags: c, winapi, banner

Hi all I made a dialog application fine which is made in C using the standard WIN32 however I am stuck on the cherry on the cake moment which is adding my banner to the application.

I have added the following the the (msg) switch

```
case WM_CREATE :
    {
        HWND MainLogo= GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_IMAGE); 
        HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,"bitmap2.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        SendMessage(MainLogo,STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)bitmap);
    }
    break;
```

The IDC_IMAGE is a picture placeholder I added in Visual Studio 2010 and the bitmap is loaded into my resource file.

Is this code in the wrong place? and is it even the correct way to load an image?

Thanks in advance.

Working Fix was to replace this in .rc file

```
ICON IDI_ICON1,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
```

in your dialog resource instead of CONTROL thanks to arx

Comment: [The documentation for `STM_SETIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "To associate an image with a static control, the control must have the proper style."

Comment: It would help if you provided more information about which step fails. Does your `GetDlgItem` return the correct window handle? Does your `LoadImage` load the image?

Answer (score 3):

`WM_CREATE` is too soon. Your child controls haven't been created yet. Try `WM_INITDIALOG` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag telling Windows to look for a file called `bitmap2.bmp`.  You say you've added the bitmap to your resources, so I guess the file can't be found.

If you want to load the bitmap from the resources, pass an instance handle and a resource ID for the first two parameters, and don't specify the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag.

Comment: still doesnt work full code now posted above. Hope someone can help me I am pulling what little hair I have out.

Comment: @ClarkSmalls Um, you say to load from a file, but you added to your resources. Make up your mind: Where is the bitmap? If in resources, then don't pass `LR_LOADFROMFILE` and instead load bitmap `IDB_BITMAP2`.

Comment: in my resource file is it defined
 
IDB_BITMAP2             BITMAP                  "bitmap2.bmp"

Then file is inside my VS2010 project complier doesnt show missing BMP or alike.

Comment: @ClarkSmalls If you want to load it from resources, then don't pass `LR_LOADFROMFILE`. Instead, pass your instance handle and bitmap ID.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do it with C you need active x or newer controls. I cant be done at all. (fixed type error)

Comment: This is nonsense.  Of course you can do it from C/C++.  How do you think ActiveX controls are implemented?

Comment: @ hakan stupid question can i use active x controls with c? I found the insert image link for that would that work.

Comment: @ClarkSmalls: embedding an ActiveX control with C is much more difficult than fixing the code you've got.  I've already explained why `LoadImage` isn't working.

Comment: Hi arx i tryed to remove the line of code you mentioned LR_LOADFROMFILE but when I do it throws up an error Error 2 
error C2660: 'LoadImageA' : function does not take 5 arguments c:\users\clark\desktop\bitmap problem\example.cpp 62 1 ComboTest

Comment: HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,"bitmap2.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,16,16;

Comment: @ClarkSmalls: Pass zero to indicate "no flags".  And, as I said, you need to pass a resource ID and instance handle.  Something like: `LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, 0);`  P.S. Prefix comments with "@arx" if you want me to see them.

Comment: @arx

Well thanks for the reply again its cool people like you are there to help out newbie idoits. 

I managed to get it to compile but still no luck added this to the intial dialog.

  HWND MainLogo= GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_STATIC);  
  HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, 0);
  SendMessage(MainLogo,STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)bitmap); 

One question how do I test the handles are valid and reading the BITMAP is it

if (bitmap == NULL)
{
print output not working!
}

Comment: @ClarkSmalls: Check the docs for [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the **Return Value** section.  It says "If the function fails, the return value is NULL".  Yes, checking "if (bitmap == NULL)" is sensible.  The quickest way to see what's failing is to step through in a debugger and check the return value of each function.

Comment: @arx thanks checked the docs for both getdlgitem and the loadimage and both should return null and neither of the 2 sections do very odd I am puzzled as to what it could be now.

Comment: @ClarkSmalls: Did you mean "both should **not** return null"?  It's just occurred to me that there are easier ways to do this.  For example, put `ICON            IDI_ICON1,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20` in your dialog resource instead of `CONTROL` and it will automatically display your app icon.

Comment: @arx yes you are right I meant are not null. Thanks for that new snippet it worked fine :-) the only last thing is now instead of my icon it will show the windows red x or the blue question mark icon does this mean the format of my .bmp is incorrect?

Comment: @ClarkSmalls: It displays whatever icon `IDI_ICON1` refers to.  If you want to use your existing bitmap you need to convert it to an icon (.ico) file.  Paid versions of Visual Studio can do this, but the Express versions can't.  Or you can use a graphics tool like GIMP.

Comment: @arx ok thanks for all your help I do appreciate it bed time now.